# ¿Como recoger o insertar un dato booleano de sqldeveloper en java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo este contructor :

```
public TiquetTO(int id, String descripcio, Date dataInici, Date dataFinal, boolean finalitzat) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcio = descripcio;
        this.dataInici = dataInici;
        this.dataFinal = dataFinal;
        this.finalitzat = finalitzat;
    }
```

este metodo DAO

```
public void create(TiquetTO tiquet) {
       Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = cf.getConnection();
            String sentencia = "INSERT INTO TIQUETS (ID,DESCRIPCIO,DATAINI,DATAFINI,FINALITZAT)"
                    + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sentencia);

            ps.setInt(1,tiquet.getId());
            ps.setString(2, tiquet.getDescripcio());
            ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) tiquet.getDataInici());
            ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) tiquet.getDataFinal());
            ps.setBoolean(5, tiquet.isFinalitzat());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Tiquet creat!");
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in SQL. " +ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Y este metodo a ejecutar en main

```
 static void crearTiquet(){
        String dataIni = "10/05/2020";
        String dataFini = "14/05/2020";

        try {
            Date dateI = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataIni);
            Date dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataFini);

            TiquetTO t1 = new TiquetTO(3,"Soy kevin", dateI, dateF, true);

            TiquetDAOImpl tiq = null;
            tiq.create(t1);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error main");
        }  
    }
```

La pregunta o duda si alguna puede ayudarme a entender es, como puedo insertar un dato boolean java al sqldeveloper?
He de decir que la columna sql el tipo de dato puse chart(1 bytes) con la restricccion que solo permita 0,1 => false/true.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Has probado a hacer algo así?  `ps.setInt(5, tiquet.isFinalitzat() ? 1 : 0);` Para mandar un 0 o un 1 en lugar de true/false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si pusiste en la BD para que espere un 0 o 1, lo mas sencillo seria hacer algo así con tu campo booleano:

```
int finalValue = tiquet.isFinalitzat() ? 1 : 0;
```

Y luego envias **finalValue** como parametro a la BD.

```
ps.setInt(5, **finalValue**);
```

O en lugar podes manejar en la BD como booleano en lugar de Char(1).

Espero que te sea de ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: Gracias esta me ha servido, pero ahora tengo otros errores, intentaré resolverlos sino pediré otra vez ayuda! gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

En el cas que mostres, no cal un  PrepareStatement. Amb un executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...") ja valdria. Potser per aquest camí descartis el problema.

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], ya que tu aporte no es claro